# Dynamically setCurrentTime in MediaElement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, mediaelement.js

I need to play a video from anywhere based on timestamp info from a transcript.

Here's the video:

`<video id="demo" width="720" height="600" controls="controls" preload="true"><source type="video/mp4" src="sample.m4v" /><track label="English" srclang="en" kind="subtitles" type="text/vtt" src="sample.vtt" /></video>`

Here's a snippet of the transcript:

```
*ABD:   yes it’s the [opposite
*JUL:   [yeah <span class="movControl" id="play" name="current_time"   value="15">&#9654;</span>
°↑i do (h) not even try° <span class="movControl" id="play" name="current_time" value="16">&#9654;</span>
```

Here's the javascript code

```
<script src="/mediaelementjs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/mediaelementjs/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    var media; // we need this global variable
    var t1 = document.getElementsByName("current_time")[0].value;
    t1 = parseInt(t1);
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("video").mediaelementplayer({
            enableKeyboard: true,
            pauseOtherPlayers: true,
            framesPerSecond: 25,
            loop: false,
            startVolume: 0.8,
            keyActions: [],
            startLanguage: 'en',
            success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                media = mediaElement; // make it available for other functions
            }
        });
        $(".movControl").on("click", function () {
            media.setCurrentTime(t1); // set starting time
            media.play();
        });
    }); // ready
```

So, when a user click on a  icon anywhere in the transcript, I want to grab its corresponding time (e.g., 15 seconds) and assign it to the MediaElement setCurrentTime function. I tried the above code but it did not work. Would you please give me some help? Much appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle mate..??

Comment: Thanks Outlooker. I have resolved the issue. Apparently, IDs need to be unique, and I ended up using onClick to pass along the timestamp info.